# Finding dimension of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

How would anyone go about this problem?

> Find dim$_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$
>   where $\alpha^{3}=2$ and $\beta^{2}=2$.

Thanks for your help, I really don't know how to go about this problem.

Comment: The sooner you learn the Tower Law, the happier you will be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by the dimension formula,
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=
[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\beta)]
[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]
$$
(where $[F:K]=\dim_K F$). Is there a root of $X^3-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=K(\alpha,\beta)$, you know that $K(\alpha)$ and $K(\beta)$ are both intermediate fields of L/K. Looking at $X^2  -2$ and $X^3 - 2$ and using the hint above, you know that [L:K] has to be at least 6, since 2 and 3 have to divide the degree. Why is the degree at most 6?